# Django Redis Cache Admin Interface

Tags: python, django, redis

I implemented Redis Caching in my Django.. However, is there a Friendly User Interface to just check the cache values. Something like you can see all the cache keys and its values in Django Admin

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status of your Redis Cache with the help of this github library,

https://github.com/erussell/django-redis-status

It is only accessible in the django-admin page.
By the way, you can always check your redis database using redis-cli.

I don't know whether I am getting your question in the correct way or not.
But this may help.